# Insert value list does not match column list on Laravel nullable()

Tags: laravel

I have a DB table with the following structure:

## Table Migration:

```
Schema::create('initiatives', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('initiative_group_id');
    $table->string('initiative_owner')->nullable();
    $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
    $table->date('end_date')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('initiative_group_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('initiative_groups')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Now, I'm trying to seed that table with some rows:

## Database seeder

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('initiatives')->insert([
        ['name' => 'A1', 'initiative_group_id' => 1, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person A'],
        ['name' => 'B1', 'initiative_group_id' => 2, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person B'],
        ['name' => 'B2', 'initiative_group_id' => 2],
        ['name' => 'D1', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'D2', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'D3', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'E1', 'initiative_group_id' => 5],
    ]);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 12;
```

So I know that I am selectively including and excluding some columns in these inserts (sometimes I have an initiative_owner and sometimes not), but can I not specify not to insert some columns as I've set them to nullable? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: can't you pass it empty like `'initiative_owner' => ''` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing multiple insertions in one go from seeder, but the length of all arrays must be the same.

```
 DB::table('initiatives')->insert([
        ['name' => 'A1', 'initiative_group_id' => 1, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person A'],
        ['name' => 'B1', 'initiative_group_id' => 2, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person B'],
        ['name' => 'B2', 'initiative_group_id' => 2], //initiative_owner is missing
        ['name' => 'D1', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'D2', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'D3', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'E1', 'initiative_group_id' => 5], //initiative_owner is missing
    ]);
```

You can set them null but don't skip.

The second option you can insert two different arrays.

```
DB::table('initiatives')->insert([
        ['name' => 'A1', 'initiative_group_id' => 1, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person A'],
        ['name' => 'B1', 'initiative_group_id' => 2, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person B'],   
        ['name' => 'D1', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'D2', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
        ['name' => 'D3', 'initiative_group_id' => 4, 'initiative_owner' => 'Person C'],
    ]);

DB::table('initiatives')->insert([
    ['name' => 'B2', 'initiative_group_id' => 2], 
    ['name' => 'E1', 'initiative_group_id' => 5], 
]);
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. It's pretty lame that you can't do it in one!

Comment: Enjoy your day @CornelVerster